# Place to put assets for dev/test in emberjs

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm using mirage to mock some data and I'd like to mock an `<img>` with the appropriate file.

The problem is that I will have to place the image in `/public/assets` and the images placed there will be deployed later on as well.

Is there a way to avoid this? I couldn't find a recommendation in the ember cli website (https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation)

I found one addon that could do this (ember-test-assets), but I'd like to avoid installing extra addons as much as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude files in `ember-cli-build.js` with some help of Broccoli

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

  // Filter your test files in 'production'
  if (EmberApp.env() === 'production') {
    return new Funnel(app.toTree(), {
      exclude: ['**/test-*'] // e.g. any file prefixxed with 'test-'
    });
  }
  return app.toTree();
};
```

References:

- `EmberApp.env()`: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/d97d96aa016fbe8108c2d2744c9823a0ea086b94/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js#L469
- `broccoli-funnel`: https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel (see `exclude`)

Comment: great answers this week! Thanks for helping with Q&A