# How to exclude a component in ember build

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-3

Short Explanation:

How to exclude all `component.hbs`, `component.hbs.js` and `this.route('component)` mention in `router.js` related to a component while ember build.

Long Explanation:

Think that you have a component in your **ember app** which you want to be **available only in the development environment** (*lets not worry about how good this approach is, for now!!*) and must be removed while building for production.

I have tried a few `ember-cli` plugins ([broccoli-funnel](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel), [ember-cli-funnel](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-funnel/)) which excludes `component.hbs.js` file but I can still see the references to the `component.hbs` and `this.route('component')` in the compiled JS file in `/dist` folder.

Comment: You might want to poke around the code for `ember-composable-helpers` (https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers/) they have a whitelist/backlist configuration for components to be included in the build.... might have some luck there.

Comment: Could you put it into an add-on? The welcome page does what you want ...

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

1. Don't exclude files or code, but *disable* with ember-feature-flags addon

Great addon: https://github.com/kategengler/ember-feature-flags

2. Exclude files from the build

As mentioned by pedro, you could checkout `ember-composable-helpers` for that. They seem to strip the files in `index.js#treeForAddon`.
https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers/blob/master/index.js#L28-L33

This might also help:
[Place to put assets for dev/test in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958155/place-to-put-assets-for-dev-test-in-emberjs/51961631#51961631)

3. Exclude code from the build

Might be a bit more complicated... you could checkout how Ember does it with their Feature Flags (although, I'm not sure if they use `defeatureify` or `babel-plugin-filter-imports`)
* Ember Feature Flags: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/feature-flags/

- Defeatureify: https://github.com/thomasboyt/defeatureify/
- https://github.com/ember-cli/babel-plugin-filter-imports

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options that would be helpful for you:

The quick way is to install [Ember-Cli-Tree-Shaker](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-tree-shaker). In your ember-cli-build.js file, you can include an `[exclude]` array of files paths always to remove. However, this is an experimental project, and follow all the disclaimers on the site.

The longer, but potentially more stable, way to strip the component from the build, is to [create an in-repo addon](https://shipshape.io/blog/ember-in-repo-addons/) and in that addon's `index.js` file, filter components in the `treeForAddon()` and `treeForAddonTemplates()` hooks. Here's an example: https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/index.js#L282